# It is given that $x.y.z=12^3$ where $x,y,z$ are positive integers.Then , how many different solutions are there for $x+y+z$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> It is given that $x.y.z=12^3$ where $x,y,z$ are positive integers.Then , how many different solutions are there for $x+y+z$?

Its answer is easy if it were $x.y=12^3$ , because there are $28$ possible $(a,b)$ pairs by $x.y=2^6 \times 3^3$ and $C(8,2) \times C(4,1) =28$.

Moreover, half of $28$ will give us the number of $x+y$ thanks to symmetry property.

Let's come to original question:

Firtly , i found the number of how many possible $x,y,x$ there exist by combination with repetition such that $C(6+3-1,6) \times C(3+3-1,3)=280$.

However , when i want to find the number of different values of $x+y+z$ , i stuck in.Because , i thought that if i divide $280$ by $3$ , i can obtain the result.However , it did not work and i dont know what i should do.

Therefore, i hope to find tricks or solutions for my problem. Moreover , what can i do for the expanding versions of this question such as $x+y+z+t$

Comment: Since addition and multiplication are both commutative, one can assume WLOG that $x \le y \le z$.

Comment: If $x,y,z = 2^{a_i}3^{b_i}$ then $x + y + z = \gcd(x,y,z) = 2^{\min a_i}3^{\min b_i}(x' + y' + z')$  Can we somehow assume that for the various possible $2^{\min a_i}3^{\min b_i}$ thatn the resulting $x'+y' + z'$ are all relatively prime and distince and we can count those all.

Comment: @fleablood $61 = 2 + 27 + 32 = 4 + 9 + 48$

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed $280$ possible ordered triples $[x,y,z]$ with $xyz=12^3$, and these have only $49$ different sums.  I don't see any easy way of counting these other than
explicit enumeration (which is easy on a computer).

Comment: It seems there are 50 unordered triples (x, y, z) with xyz = p^6 q^3 for any two primes p ≠ q. q^3 can be divided into (1,1,q^3), (1, q, q^2) or (q, q, q). p^6 can be divided into (1,p,p^5), (1, p^2, p^4), (p, p^2, p^3) with 3 different numbers, (1, 1, p^6), (1, p^3, p^3), (p, p, p^4) with two equal numbers, and (p^2, p^2, p^2) with three equal numbers. Combining these gives 50 unordered triples. So you would have found two unordered triples with equal sum.

Comment: I.e. $61 = 2+27+32 = 4+9+48$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define an order that $a < b$ if the power of $3$ that divides $a$ is less than the power of $3$ that divide $a$ or those powers are equal then if power of $2$ that divides $a$ is *larger* then the power than divides $b$

Then wolog $x \le y \le z$ and we need to consider the cases

$x=y=z$

$x=y < z$

$x < y = z$

$x < y < z$.

Case 1: $x = y = z$ so $3^1|x,y,z$ and $2^2|x,y,z$ and $x=y=z=12$ and $x+y+z = 36$.

Case 2: $x=y < z$ then either $3|x,y,z$ and $2^3|x,y$ or $3^3|z$ and $1,2,4|x,y$

That gives us $4$ more options $x=y=24;z=3$ or $x=y=1,2,4; z = 27\cdot(2^6,2^3,1)$

So that's $5$ options so far.

Case 3: $x< y = z$ then $3|x,y,z$ and either $2^6|x$ or $2^4|x, 2|y,z$

So that's $2$ more options. $7$ so far.

Case 4: $x < y < z$.

either $3|y; 3^2|z$ or $3|x,y,z$ and $2^4|x; 2^2|y$ or $2^3|x; 2^2|y; 2|z$

The latter two give us $2$ more for $9$.

And finally The first case we can have the powers of $2$ distributed any way.

That $3$ times $1,1,2^6$.

$1$ times $1,2^2,2^4$ and $2$ times $1,2^3,2^3$.

And $2$ times $2,2,2^4$.  And $6$ times $2,2^2,2^3$.

And $1$ times $2^2,2^2,2^2$ so that is $3+1+2+2+6+1=15$.

So a total of $24$.

I'm taking it on faith, perhaps incorrectly,  that we can show these solutions are pairwise relatively prime so distinct.

And as Robert Isreal got $49$ sums I'm obviously making an error. Probably missing some options.

Still I'll leave this up as a strategy that I think is valid.